# Meteor: reference other javascript classes in different directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In my meteor application. I defined a `BaseController`in `base_controller.js`:

```
BaseController = RouteController.extend({
    layoutTemplate: 'mainLayout'
});
```

Then I defined `PostController` in `post_controller.js`:

```
PostController = BaseController.extend({
});
```

If I put `base_controller.js` and `post_controller.js` in same directory, no error founds. But if I put in different directory, such as `base_controller.js` in `controller` and `post_controller.js` in `controller/post` I will meet exception when running application:

> ReferenceError: BaseController is not defined

My question is: how can I divide those javascript file into different directory? I need to do this, because my application will have many controllers so put all controllers into same directory (without any child directory) will make project hard for maintenance.

Thanks :)

Comment: Check the naming of the directories you have both files. Meteor loads alphabetically. So, if the directory with your BaseController comes after your PostController extension then BaseController is not instantiated/defined yet. Directory depth also matters, but I can't recall whether deepest is first or shallow. http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand how Meteor loads your files. See sub-section **File Load Order**: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp

#### From the docs:

There are several load ordering rules. They are applied sequentially to all applicable files in the application, in the priority given below:

1. HTML template files are always loaded before everything else
2. Files beginning with main. are loaded last
3. Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
4. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
5. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

If you want your files to be loaded first, put them in ***lib*** directory in the root of your project or in any subdirectory.

Your PostController depends on BaseController, so I would put BaseController into ***lib*** folder.

If you need to specify exact file load order, you can create a package with desired functionality. You can specify exact file load order only in packages.

Comment: All my controllers are inside lib folder. More specific, PostController is in` `lib/controller/post` and BaseController is in `lib/controller`. So as rules I have read, BaseController should be loaded first. nevertheless, error still occur. thanks :)

Comment: No, files in subdirectories are loaded first so files in `lib/controller/post` are loaded and then files in `lib/controller` are loaded. The solution for this would be to create another folder called `lib/controller/0base` and put base controller there. Prefix `0` will ensure that the folder will be loaded before others.

Answer (score 1):

If both are in the lib/ directory, I think the answer is from 4 and 5 from the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp):

4. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
5. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

So it should be the case that `lib/controller/post/PostController` would get loaded before `lib/controller/BaseController`, since its path is deeper.

I think the solution is probably to move them both into `lib/controller` so that BaseController gets loaded first, since it will be first alphabetically.

Comment: @tomashromnik Sorry for not commenting on your answer, I do not (yet) have the necessary rep to comment...